# Running liquibase within .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, liquibase

For some reason there's no documentation on running liquibase inside .Net Core.

How would I run migration commands directly in .NET?

I would like to do something like this:

```
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase()
liquibase.runUpdates() ?
```

Ability to create a runner class and run commands

```
// create the Liquibase runner object
var runner = new CommandLineRunner();

// configure the runner properties
runner.SetChangeLog("path/to/changelog.xml");
runner.SetUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase");
runner.SetUsername("myusername");
runner.SetPassword("mypassword");

// run Liquibase
runner.Run();
```

I read at this post that the .Net Port is available https://forum.liquibase.org/t/using-liquibase-in-a-net-environment-net-port-required/514, but couldn't find any documentation.

There is a Nuget available https://www.nuget.org/packages/Liquibase.Cli, however, adding it to the project, it doesn't detect the package

```
using Liquibase; //doesn't detect
using Liquibase.Cli; //doesn't detect
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for Liquibase in .NET. However, you can call the Liquibase command line inside your .NET code, just like any other external process.

One example related to the nuget reference, is the same author uses the Liquibase CLI from Cake. You can see more here https://github.com/papauorg/Cake.Liquibase.